# How do I run Delphi 7 on Windows 7 without disabling UAC?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7

I had the bad idea of switching to Windows 7 (32 bit) and now my old Delphi 7 won't work properly. Actually it worked just fine until yesterday but (I suppose) after some MS Windows updates, it crashes if I double click a DPR file. However, it works if I run as administrator or if I start Delphi IDE without double clicking a DPR file (and than loading that DPR). So, obviously it is a UAC issue. I am really pissed of that I switched to Win 7 which is not most different (better) than Win XP. If I have to switch off UAC (and with it the only big improvement that Win 7 brings - the security) than for real I will have no advantage from Win 7.
So, how to make Delphi work without disabling the UAC?

I hope that other people that had this problem found a solution.
:)

---

Update:

- I have tried already to give Delphi rights to write in its "c:\Program File\Borland\Delphi folder". No luck.
- I don't want to run it in Admin mode (this includes XP mode) since it will be running at a different level. Some API calls will not fail (since it is running in admin mode). Drag and drop from non-admin program and other similar features will also not work.
- Security is not a problem. I don't mindlessly download any piece of software I get from random people (read spammers) via email or from obscure web site so I don't get virused. Oh... and I don't use IE for browsing :)

Comment: So... *Wine*, which doesn't even run on Windows, runs Delphi 7 better than Windows 7 itself? Yes, Windows 7 has backwards compatibility, yes, yes it does.

Comment: Probably Wine was optimized for Win XP.

Comment: How is it "obviously a UAC issue" if you can start Delphi as a normal user and open the DPR file without problems?

Comment: @Rob. Since Delphi is running in Admin mode, the UAC must be the one that is preventing it from working properly in non-admin mode. For example not letting it to write to HKLM (I already gave Delphi permissions to write to Program files\borland). Anyway IT MUST be something related to the way the command line parameters are passed to Delphi when I double click a DPR/PAS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. It was a DDE problem.
I just deleted the ddeexec key associated with Delphi projects.

Answer (score 7):

Try installing Delphi outside %program files%. It's the best bet for software that wasn't designed with UAC (or guidelines on where to store user data since about NT4) in mind.

I am running Delphi 5 and 7 on Windows 7 that way, no problems thus far.

Comment: This method works very well.  We have several developers using Delphi 6.  We've used it in Vista 32-bit, Win7 32-bit, and Win7 64-bit, all with UAC turned on.  We install to C:\Programs\Borland, rather than C:\Program Files\Borland.

Comment: I already gave Delphi rights to write to Program File. I don't think this is a problem anymore. But I agree with you that MANY programs should be installed in other folder than Program Files. Thanks Microsoft for this new trend!

Comment: Use SysInternals Process Monitor to check what the last thing is the IDE did before it went down. It's a bit of effort, but it is very likely to pinpoint UAC issues. For one thing, I would question whether your "I gave Delphi rights to write to xxx" action was effective.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is the `XP Mode` of Windows 7 Professional. I recommend to convert and use the XP Mode VM with VMware Player. Then it is fast and reliable.

*Update*: So in fact it's not the `XP Mode` itself, which I recommend, but the XP license which goes along with it. You can duplicate it as many times you need,  but (of course) use only one instance at a time.

Comment: In this case would apps running under the debugger also run under XP?

Comment: Have you tried running Delphi in "XP Mode"?  We tried and it was absolutely terrible.  I would not recommend doing this without using some form of a walkthrough.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, of course! I have forgotten to mention that I use the converted XP Mode with VMware Player.

Comment: @Gerry: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @splash I think he is asking if you can debug windows 7 apps from delphi in xp mode

Comment: VMware Player establishes a network connection with your Windows 7 host machine (Bridged/NAT/Host Only), so debugging applications with the Remote Debugger should be possible as in any other network.

Comment: @Splash - if Delphi is running in a XP Mode VM, any apps running under the Delphi debugger will also run in the VM. You will not be able to debug under Win7.

Comment: @Gerry: However, that's why I talk about *Remote Debugging*: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging

Comment: I don't want to run it in Admin mode (this includes XP mode) since it will be running at a different level. Some API calls will not fail (since it is running in admin mode). Drag and drop from non-admin program and other similar features will also not work.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way install it as administrator ,or search google for the appropriate file if you are still having problems then the folder is probably set to read only so you must change that.

This actually works this is how i made mine work